# Internal server error Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

First time learning Flask and I am trying to build things following a tutorial. I am getting this message in my browser when I input this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/index 

127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2014 19:37:41] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

I'm not sure why I am getting this error. Could someone help me out and tell me why? I am new to Flask and web development

code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response, redirect, render_template
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap


app = Flask(__name__)
manager = Manager(app)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/user/<name>')
def user(name):
    return render_template('user.html', name = name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.run(debug = True)
    manager.run()
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} Index {% block title %}

{% block head %}
    <!-- Uses super() to retain the original contents-->
    {{ super() }}
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
{% endblock %}  
{% block body %}
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

This is my project structure:

```
/Flask_0_11
   /templates
      base.html
      index.html
      user.html
   hello.py
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a template syntax error in your `index.html`.

The title block should be closed with `{% endblock %}`:

```
{% block title %} Index {% endblock %}
```

You can turn on the `DEBUG` configuration for debugging. Because you use `Flask-Script`, you can pass the `-d` option to the runserver command.

e.g.

```
python hello.py runserver -d
```

Comment: or `app.debug = True`

Answer (score 5):

First of all try to run the app using

```
python manage.py runserver -d
```

This will run your flask app in debug mode showing the errors encountered in your app making correction easily.

Secondly,there may be error due to no WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True with SECRET_KEY in your config file.